# Docker Desktop Installation failed: one prerequisite is not fulfilled on Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker

I have a problem when installing a Docker Desktop 2.3.0.3
"Installation failed: one prerequisite is not fullfilled"
Docker Desktop requires Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise (15063+) or Windows 10 Home (19018+).

My Computer System Specification:
OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version: 10.0.10240 Build 10240
RAM: 8Gb

I have tried manually Install Hyper-V and Containers in my Computer, but still failed to install the desktop docker.. Anyone can help me? Im need your help.

Comment: Please first take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

You need to install Windows 10 Home 2004 build which was released on May 2020, you can use Microsoft's update assistant to manually get the update if it's not showing up for you on Windows.

Get it here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/)

> Docker Toolbox is an installer for quick setup and launch of a Docker
>   environment on older Mac and Windows systems that do not meet the
>   requirements of the new Docker Desktop for Mac and Docker Desktop for
>   Windows apps.

Comment: So its not possible to install Docker Desktop in my computer?

Comment: possible once you update Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Version: 10.0.10240 to 15063+

Answer (score 0):

The actual required Windows version is greater than what it says in the installer GUI.
It might be a typo! and according to Docker this has happened before:

> Docker actually requires Windows build xxxxx or greater - we're
> working on the typo in the installer gui, but you'll need to update
> your Windows to proceed. (Jan 8, 2018)

Just Update Windows and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot update the system use choco

1. Install following the official Сhocolatey documentation: https://chocolatey.org/install
2. After installation, run the command `choco install docker-desktop` or follow the official installation documentation https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/docker-desktop